# Python an Unzipping of files

Tags: python, csv, unzip

I am a novice programmer and recently have been facing an issue while unzipping a file.

So my file name is - `ABC_year_company_id_DEF.zip` which will contain `ABC_year_company_id_DEF.csv`.

So my code is specific to unzipping and extracting a csv from it. It works perfectly fine.
Recently I came across a glitch.

So my file name is - `ABC_year_company/somename_id_DEF.zip` which will contain `ABC_year_company/somename_id_DEF.csv`.

Due to the slash, it takes as a folder - `ABC_year_company` and file `somename_id_DEF.csv`

This is creating huge problems for me.

Below is the code I tried but didn't work :

```
zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(request_download.content))
with zipfile.ZipFile(dir_save_survey,'r') as zip_ref:
    print(zip_ref)
    for file_info in zip_ref.infolist():
        # Manipulate the file name if needed
        file_name = file_info.filename.replace('/', '-')  # Replace slashes with underscores

        # Construct the full path to extract the file
        extract_path = os.path.join(dir_save_survey, file_name)

        # Extract the file
        zip_ref.extract(file_info, extract_path)
# zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(request_download.content)).extractall(dir_save_survey)
```

I would request you to please help me with this. Apologies for any lapses in the format of the question or structure. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: File names can't contain `/` in them. And please explain what "huge problems" means.

Comment: To me it looks like `ABC_year_company/somename_id_DEF.zip` is referencing a sub-directory in `dir_save_survey`.